# Is it possible to get a function result with columns which are not in the group by (SQL)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, max

I am trying to get the last registration date of a course, but I want to know the **id** of thar record. As MAX is a function, I must use group by **id**, which I do not want, because the result is very different (From only one record to each record per id).

Which is the way to manage a query like this?:

```
SELECT id, MAX(registration_date) AS registration_date 
FROM courses;
```

Because it gives an error and I must do this to avoid it:

```
SELECT id, MAX(registration_date) AS registration_date 
FROM courses
GROUP BY id;
```

And I do not want the result of the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`rank()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) window function for that:

```
SELECT id
FROM   (SELECT id, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY registration_date DESC) AS rk
        FROM   courses)
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use a sub query like this:

```
select * 
from [dbo].[Courses]
where registration_date = 
(select max(registration_date) 
from [dbo].[Courses])
```

but with only a date to match this may return more than one record. 
If possible, include more fields in the where clause to narrow it down.

Comment: That is no valid SQL for Postgres (or standard SQL)